# Could not find table 'projects'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, rake

I am getting the following error message on my localhost:3000/project/new

> Could not find table 'projects'
>       Extracted source (around line #8):
>       @project = Project.new(params[:project])  --- line8

I am rendering a table from a partial in my projects folder

```
<h1>This is a form</h1>

<%= form_for(@project) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :plan %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :plan %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

to the new file/action in the projects folder

```
<h1>Submit a new project here</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>
```

This is my Project Model

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates :title, :uniqueness => true
end
```

This is my Routes

```
dsfasfd::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :project
  devise_for :users
```

root to: "home#index"

I ran rake:db migrate but its not doing anything, not creating a db and I can't find anything in the schema about projects either. Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, why won't my rake create a table?

Comment: Do you have a migration file under db/migrate for projects?

Comment: No, do I have to create that manually? Isn't a rake db:migrate supposed to do that for me?

Comment: You have to generate a migration file and then you have to migrate it.

Comment: Will create db:migrate followed by rake db:migrate do the trick? Sorry I'm new and trying to learn!

Comment: No it will not.Firstly generate a migration file by rails g migration products title:string description:string plan:string and then do rake db:migrate

Comment: I did that and then restarted my rails server and I get the same error message... There is a db now though so that's some progress

Comment: The database is mostly empty though and no mention of projects in the schema still

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly generate a migration file.

```
rails g migration products title:string description:string plan:string
```

and then migrate it

```
rake db:migrate
```

Follow this [Guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#writing-a-migration).You really need this.

**Update:**

Seems like you have generated an empty migration file.Now have to do

1.Open that migration file and add these lines under the `def`

```
t.string :title

t.string :description

t.string :plan
```

2.Do `rake db:migrate` after that.

Comment: Did this and that created the db file but its mostly empty and i still get the same error

Comment: Now you have your projects schema file under db/migrate?

Comment: Not sure what that means. But now there is a randomnumbers_project.rb file under db/migrate This is what is inside the randomnumbers_project.rb     class Experiment < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
  end
end
               only this inside that file

Comment: Can I undo the migration and just generate a model that does the table for me? I think what I am missing is that the way I went about doing this I have to do the table myself

Comment: Updated!Please Check it!

Comment: @user3408293 Please accept the answer if you are satisfied with it.

Comment: Didn't solve the problem, I have scratched everything and started from the beginning.